# Dynamic Modal not displaying in table

Tags: php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a mail system and I want to show the full email in a modal using a button in the mail table.

I have code which is supposed to do this:

```
<?php
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass, $db);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: ". $conn->connect_error);
} 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM  `mail` ORDER BY `id` DESC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

// output data of each row
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {


echo '<tr><td>'.$row['name'].'</td><td>'.$row['subject'].'</td><td>'.$row['date'].'</td><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#MyModal">Launch demo modal</button></td></tr>';
echo '<div class="modal fade"><div class="modal-dialog"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button><h4 class="modal-title">'.$row['subject'].'</h4></div><div class="modal-body">'.$row['message'].'</div><div class="modal-footer"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button></div></div><!-- /.modal-content --></div><!-- /.modal-dialog --></div><!-- /.modal -->';
}
} else {
echo "";
}
$conn->close();
?>

echo '$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {$('#myInput').focus()})</script>'
```

But the modal doesnt display. What is going wrong and how do I fix this. Also If I place the modal button and code outside the table and outside the php its fine.

Comment: You are not triggering the modal, `$('#myModal').modal('show');` so this should be `echo '$('#myModal').modal('show').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {$('#myInput').focus()})</script>'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. I used a dynamic iframe. Using the native bootstrap popup system.